# Sending template messages through Textlocal API

Tags: python

I am getting the response:

> {"errors":[{"code":204,"message":"Invalid message content"}],"status":"failure"}

When I try to submit a message using this template I have registered with Textlocal:

> Thank you for registering with ***. Please enter the verification code %%|OTP^{"inputtype" : "text", "maxlength" : "6"}%% to complete the registration.

How should I send a message with this template? My current code is:

```
def sending_sms(number,otp):
    url = 'http://api.textlocal.in/send/'
    msg = 'Thank you for registering with RTM. Please enter the verification code %%|OTP^{"inputtype" : "text", "maxlength" : "6"}%% to complete the registration.'
    post_fields = ({"username":"admin@example.in","password":"P@ssword","numbers":number,"message":msg})

    request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())
    print request
    json = urlopen(request).read().decode()
    print json
    return json
```

Answer (score 2):

You are sending the template as your message.  You need to be sending a filled-in template (i.e. replace an actual OTP code, not `%%|OTP...`.

From the docs:

> **How to send templates via API?**
>
> Textlocal checks your messages against all your approved templates and passes the
>   message only if it is an exact match with any of the approved templates in your account.
>
> 1. Fetch the dynamic parameters from your database/application and pass the final
>      message content in API
>
>    - For Example: If your approved template is:
>
>      `Thank you for registering with Textlocal. Your verification code is XXXX`
>
>      the message content that needs to be passed is:
>
>      `Thank you for registering with Textlocal. Your verification code is 1123`
>
>      (where the code is generated by your application)
> 2. In your code, the dynamic parameters have to be assigned a variable (ideally a long string or an array) which is assigned a specific value from your database/application depending on the mobile number.
>
>    - For Example: in PHP,
>
>      `$message = rawurlencode('Thank you for registering with Textlocal. Your verification code is $otp')`
>
>      where `$otp` is the identifier in your code for the dynamic parameter.
>
> Points to note:
>
> 1. Template name, placeholder text are all for your reference. They should not be added in API.
> 2. ‘Message’ parameter in Textlocal API should only have the complete message content with
>      the dynamic parameters replaced. (Refer: http://api.textlocal.in/docs/ for parameter details)
> 3. All special characters needs to be URL encoded (Refer:
>      http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ for the encoded value)
> 4. If your template has a newline character – replace the newline feed with %n in API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as per the @Grisha Levit answer. you just have to send the OTP in message variable itself instead of %%|OTP^{"inputtype" : "text", "maxlength" : "6"}%%.

To solve the question

Change this

```
msg = 'Thank you for registering with RTM. Please enter the verification code %%|OTP^{"inputtype" : "text", "maxlength" : "6"}%% to complete the registration.'
```

To This

```
otp = 123456
msg = 'Thank you for registering with RTM. Please enter the verification code {otp} to complete the registration.'
```